# How to patch Wildfly 11 with Hibernate Validator 6.0.4.(JSR 380)?

Tags: hibernate, wildfly

Following [these](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_updating_hibernate_validator_in_wildfly) instructions from the docs, I am trying to patch WildFly 11 with Hibernate Validator 6.0.4.(JSR 380 reference implementation)

**However, I cannot find the patch file on** [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/6.0.4.Final/). There seem to be only the distribution packages, not wildfly-11.0.0.Final-patch.zip. Is it missing ? Where can I get it ?

Alternatively, how can I get the file with Maven ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: I created a new dummy maven project, added the dependency to my POM and ran maven install:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-modules</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4.Final</version>
    <classifier>wildfly-11.0.0.Final-patch</classifier>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

The patch file has been downloaded to .m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator-modules\6.0.4.Final